# Ligatures Stopped Working in XeLateX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I was recently writing a beamer presentation using Xelatex to load Arial Narrow as the font (work insists on Arial Narrow!), and using Ligatures=TeX to ensure double hyphens and quotations marks are sorted out for me. Everything was fine for ages, but all of a sudden the double hyphens and quotation marks are not being picked up correctly.

I'm using Tex Live 2015 on Windows 7, here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setsansfont{Arial Narrow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some texts with some hyphens--hypens, and some ``quotation marks''.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

On my computer, this MWE will generate a slide using Arial Narrow, but the double hyphen won't be corrected, and the quotes will remain explicitly `` and ''.

I have the same problem no matter how I call fontspec, whether directly or with xltxtra. It also makes no difference whether the Ligatures=TeX is put in the original call or declared after as I have done here.

But the really weird bit to me is what happens when I uncomment out the fontenc call. If I uncomment the call as it is above then absolutely nothing happens. Yet if I then move it to anywhere after the call to xltxtra (or a direct call to fontspec) then the double hyphens etc get picked up again - BUT, the Arial Narrow font is no longer loaded and instead some serif font is used. Previously I had no problems, regardless of when and where fontenc was called.

I've no idea why everything worked fine and then sudden broke. Has there been an update to Tex Live recently that could have done this? Or a Windows 7 update? I keep both updated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. On my system (MacTeX2015, MacOSX 10.11.1 "El Capitan"), XeLaTeX produces no output at all, whereas LuaLaTeX runs fine, ie., produces smart quotes and an en-dash.

Comment: On my system (TeX Live 2015), I get the ligatures as expected. You should add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` and do `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead of `\usepackage{xltxtra}` (but these are recommendations, and the output doesn't change).

Comment: I'm using TeX Live 2015 in Windows 7, and I get the expected hyphens and quotation marks.

Comment: Well this is very strange. Just ran the same code on OSX at home and no problem. Still giving me nonsense on Windows.

Comment: Update: uploading the `fontspec` package and using `\setmainfont` instead of `setsansfont` (and *not* loading `xltxtra`) makes your code run under XeLaTeX as well on my system -- *and* produce the same output that `LuaLaTeX` does.

Comment: That gives me an output, but it gives (I think) helvetica as the font, not Arial Narrow! This is so weird as it was all working fine for ages. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: At least with egreg's suggestions, it works fine on GNU/Linux with TL 2015, although I have to substitute the Linux equivalent for Arial Narrow (Liberation Sans Narrow on my system). Both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Quick update after coming back from holidays. I tried a few other tricks such as rolling back the xetex etc package versions as I noticed it stopped working around the time of a package revision, but that didn't help. I was going to see if switching to MikTeX made any difference, but tried a complete reinstall of TeXLive before that, just in case, and it seems to have fix the issue. No idea why it broke and why that fixed it, though I suspect something to do with one or more of the xetex package updates.